# Read xml with out any tag reference?

Tags: java, xml

In my current xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">

<properties>

    <entry key="Azmth Interval">30</entry>

    <entry key="Lowest Elevation">true</entry>

    <entry key="Offset Latitude">18.89</entry>

    <entry key="Plot Size">500</entry>

    <entry key="Offset Display Range">250.0</entry>

</properties>
```

I use tag name (hard coded) as a reference to retrieve the value.

Is it possible for me, to just blanking read the xml with out any any reference, as i have write the data into HDF compound data set, just like copy paste..

Comment: can you show you xml/xsd file?

Comment: How do i attach file for viewing...

Comment: Edit your question and copy-paste it :) select the code and press ctrl+k...phew

Comment: Thanks, but there are some technical issues with angular brackets in the editor, so a part of the xml I have shown in the question with out angular bracket